# Merge two row values

Tags: r

I'm very new in R. I've data like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri5G4.png)

I need to merge 'U' and Unknown values and convert these like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3RjC.png)

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rename the rows begining with "U" so they are both "Unknown", and then calculate the sum of each column with the same Age Band:

```
library(tidyverse)

example_df <-data.frame(
  Age_band = c("0-15", "16-24", "25-59", "60+", "U", "Unknown"),
  Total = c(54, 123, 7893, 256, 34, 78),
  Percentage = c(0.0064, 0.014577, 0.935411, 0.030339, 0.004029, 0.009244))
  
  example_df %>% 
#Change vector type
  mutate(Age_band = as.character(Age_band))%>% 
#Rename so that rows that begin with "U" are made "Unknown"
  mutate(Age_band = ifelse(grepl("^U",Age_band),"Unknown",Age_band))%>% 
#Sum the columns by age
  group_by(Age_band)%>% 
  summarize(across(.cols = everything(),sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(
    Age_Band = c("0-15", "16-24", "25-59", "60+", "U", "Unknown"),
    Total = c(54, 123, 7893, 256, 34, 78),
    Percentage = c(0.0064, 0.014577, 0.935411, 0.030339, 0.004029, 0.009244)
)
    
df[6 ,2:3] <- df[5, 2:3] + df[6,2:3]
df <- df[-5, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, you can first rename `U`and then `aggregate` over `Total`and `Percentage`:

```
df$Age_Band[df$Age_Band=="U"] <- "Unknown" 
aggregate(df[c("Total", "Percentage")], list(df$Age_Band), sum)
  Group.1 Total Percentage
1    0-15    54   0.006400
2   16-24   123   0.014577
3   25-59  7893   0.935411
4     60+   256   0.030339
5 Unknown   112   0.013273
```